# Explain me 2 lines of this shell script

Tags: bash, shell, file-exists, cp

What does this mean?

```
if [ -f $2/$1 ]
```

and this line:

```
cp $1 $2/$1
```

Does `$2/$1`  represent a file, because it's associated with `-f`?

```
#!/bin/bash
if test $# -ne 2 
then
  echo "Numbers of argument invalid"
else
  if [ -f $2/$1 ]
  then
    echo "file already exist , replace ?"
    read return
    if test $return = 'y'
    then
      cp $1 $2/$1
    else
      exit
    fi

  else
    cp $1 $2/$1
  fi
fi
```

Comment: BTW, the line is buggy. Put it through http://shellcheck.net/ for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
./script.sh "tmp.txt" "/project"
echo $1 = tmp.txt
echo $2 = /project
$1 - file name
$2 - directory
if [ -f $2/$1 ] - checks if file exists, -f for files, -d for directory
cp $1 $2/$1 - copy file to directory/file_name
if [ -f /project/tmp.txt ]
cp tmp.txt /project/tmp.txt
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help  . Now I understand where was my problem ,  / just represent the path.

Answer (score 0):

Given 2 arguments / names (`$2` and `$1`), this is testing to ensure that a file under directory `$2` with name `$1` exists.  If so, then it copies a local file indicated by `$1` into directory `$2` with the same name.

However, per your following example, it is put to use a little differently.  If the file doesn't already exist in the destination, it immediately copies a file into a subdirectory with the name specified by `$2`.  If the file does exist in the destination, it first prompts the user if it is o.k. to overwrite the existing file.

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html

Comment: I thought that / represent a arithmetical expressoin whereas it's just the path thanks