# Shell : What does this script do?

Tags: bash, shell, cp

```
#!/bin/bash
if test $# -ne 2
  then
  echo "Error : Invalid number of arguments"
else
  if [ -d $1 ]
    then
    if [[ $2 =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]
    then
      ls -l $1 | while read line
      do
        eval "echo $line | cut -d' ' -f5" | while read ln
        do
          if [[ $ln -gt $2 ]]
          then
            echo $line
          fi
        done
      done
    else
      echo $2" is not a integer"
    fi
  else
      echo "The repertory "$1" does not exist "
  fi
fi
```

The question was to make cpp , that works like  the command cp . The script it's supposed  to react correctly if we don't give 2 argument. I don't understand what this script do from line 10 .

This code is the following of this post [Explain me 2 lines of this shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33331858/shell-explain-me-2-line-of-this-code-solved).

Thanks

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think you might be on the verge of abusing the SO system if you keep asking questions like this this way.

Comment: Sorry ifi'm not correct but I'm confused of what this script really do . In my opinion he doesn't respond to the asked question ...

Comment: @Alba, ...but the point of StackOverflow is to build a Q&A knowledgebase. It's not a general discussion forum; questions should be asked in such a way as to be helpful to other people as well as the asker, not just at the time at which the question is asked, but in the future as well. These questions aren't effectively formulated for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Without working through the code line by line and explaining it, I would point you at http://explainshell.com, which takes lines of shell code and puts commentary from the manual on each parameter.

E.g, this is part of line 12 above: http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=echo+%24line+%7C+cut+-d%27+%27+-f5

It should help you go through it line by line and work out what is going on.

Comment: Finally i think my problem is  her : eval "echo $line | cut -d' ' -f5" | while read ln

Comment: I'm not sure but  I think this script  doesn't respond to the asked question

Answer (score 0):

In words: It selects the lines from `ls -l` from a directory `$1` which have a size bigger than `$2`.

If that code is in a file called script.sh, it is called like:

```
$ ./script.sh /home/user 130000
```

And it will print all lines of `ls -l /home/user` which have a size bigger than 130000.

I do not know why the eval in:

```
eval "echo $line | cut -d' ' -f5" | while read ln
```

The line will work the same as:

```
echo $line | cut -d' ' -f5 | while read ln
```